# Visual Studio Code Errors on Tagged Union Type

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to implement a tagged union type pattern for my action creators in a redux app. The ts compiles without a problem but My IDE, `Visual Studio Code 1.26.1` is giving me an error.

> > [ts] Type 'boolean | { open: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
> >       Type '{ open: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

The typescript version reported in the bottom right is `Typescript 3.0` which is the version I'm using in my project. If I understand typescript correctly, it should discriminate based on my type value and infer correctly what type my payload would be. Again this seems to be working from a ts perspective, but it's annoying the vs-code is giving me trouble.

**reducer**

```
import { Action } from '../actions';

interface State {
  open: boolean;
};

const defaultState : State = {
  open: false,
};

export default (state = defaultState, { type, payload } : Action) : State => {
  switch(type) {
    case 'PASSWORD/OPEN':
      return { ...state, open: payload } // ERROR here on open property
  }
}
```

**actions/index.ts**

```
import { PasswordAction, openPassword, closePassword } from './password';
export type Action = PasswordAction;
export default {
  openPassword,
  closePassword,
};
```

**actions/password.ts**

```
interface OpenAction {
  type: 'PASSWORD/OPEN';
  payload: boolean;
}

interface CloseAction {
  type: 'PASSWORD/CLOSE';
  payload: { open: boolean; };
}

export type PasswordAction = OpenAction | CloseAction;

export const openPassword = () : OpenAction => ({
  type: 'PASSWORD/OPEN',
  payload: true,
});

export const closePassword = () : CloseAction => ({
  type: 'PASSWORD/CLOSE',
  payload: {open: false},
});
```

**Disclaimer**

This may not be directly programming related and therefore potentially off topic. I was going to post the question first on their GitHub page, but the issue checklist says to ask questions here. Since I am not 100% certain that this is a bug, I thought I should check here first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the type guards associated with discriminated unions to work you can't destructure the union. If you do Typescript will not be able to keep track that the destructed variables are related in any way. This will work :

```
export default (state = defaultState, a : Action) : State => {
  switch(a.type) {
    case 'PASSWORD/OPEN':
      return { ...state, open: a.payload }
  }
}
```